# SQL - Distinct in case

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to use a distinct with a case:

```
create table project_reports (id integer, project_id integer, keyword_id integer, position integer);

insert into project_reports
values
(1,  1,    1,   4),
(2,  1,    1,   5),
(3,  1,    1,   6),
(5,  1,    2,   7),
(6,  1,    2,   8),
(7,  1,    3,   5),
(8,  1,    3,   7);
```

Query:

```
SELECT
  pr.position,
  CASE WHEN pr.position BETWEEN 4 AND 10 THEN keyword_id ELSE NULL END AS pos4
FROM
  project_reports pr
```

I want the values on the column pos4 to be distinct.

Expected:

```
  4-1
  7-2
  5-3
```

I have tried multiples things but nothing seems to work.

Thanks

Comment: Can you tell us what you would like the output to look like? You said you want the values on column "pos4" to be distinct, but the scope of your query includes pr.position, so.... how can it be distinct? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6c068/1

Comment: Your case expression is redundant since every value of `position` is between 4 and 10 so your example is not representative.

Comment: Output should be   4-1
  7-2
  5-3

Comment: So it appears you want the *minimum* value of `position`, see below answer.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can have a distinct value for `pos4` (essentially the same value as `keyword_id`) is to choose which value of `position` to use.

For example the following returns distinct values and selects the minimum value of `position` for each:

```
select Min(position),
  case when position between 4 and 10 then keyword_id end as pos4
from project_reports
group by case when position between 4 and 10 then keyword_id end
```